# вывод изображения из массива для div

Tags: javascript, html, css, массивы

Нужно взять фоновое изображение для div исходя из номера текущего вопроса.

```js
const вопросыОсновнойМассив = [
{правильныйОтвет: 4,
ссылка: "https://b1.m24.ru/c/1060947.730xp.jpg"},
{правильныйОтвет: 2,
ссылка: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mdn/beginner-html-site/gh-pages/images/firefox-icon.png"},
{правильныйОтвет: 3,
ссылка: "https://b1.m24.ru/c/1060984.730xp.jpg"}
];
let НомерТекущегоВопроса=0;
document.querySelector('.картинка').style.backgroundImage = `url("${вопросыОсновнойМассив[НомерТекущегоВопроса]['ссылка']}")`;
```

```html
<div class="картинка"></div>
```

Comment: [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: я Вам давал уже ответ на похожий вопрос. из того ответа можно спокойно понять, как сделать это.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

стили для класса `.картинка` не заданы. у него нулевая высота

```js
const вопросыОсновнойМассив = [
{правильныйОтвет: 4,
ссылка: "https://b1.m24.ru/c/1060947.730xp.jpg"},
{правильныйОтвет: 2,
ссылка: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mdn/beginner-html-site/gh-pages/images/firefox-icon.png"},
{правильныйОтвет: 3,
ссылка: "https://b1.m24.ru/c/1060984.730xp.jpg"}
];
let НомерТекущегоВопроса=0;
document.querySelector('.картинка').style.backgroundImage = `url("${вопросыОсновнойМассив[НомерТекущегоВопроса]['ссылка']}")`;
```

```css
.картинка {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="картинка"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Все написано правильно, проверил у себя - все работает, у тебя скорее всего проблемы с отображением: проверь размеры и стили блока через инспектор хрома.